# Can you please help identify this plant

Tags: identification

[image]

The plant I am referring to is the thin dangling plant. It seems to be growing well, but I have no idea what it is. [image]

Comment: I think it's hard to tell because the plant is very etiolated/stretched out due to not enough sunlight.  The Jade in the picture has the same problem.   Can you take a up close picture of the very end of one of these long branches.  So, we can see what the leaves look like when they first emerge.    Thank you.

Comment: I got the best shoot I could. The leaves are very small

Comment: I'm very intrigued by this - the plant looks remarkably like Elodea nuttallii https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elodea_nuttallii but I've never known it to grow anywhere other than submerged or partially submerged in water...

Answer (score -1):

It is Sedum rupestre 'Angelina'.  In lower light conditions it will be more green than yellow.  In very intense sunlight it will even have some orange and even a touch of red.   It is very etiolated/stretched out due to not enough sunlight.  The leaves of 'Angelina' will curve backwards if there is lots of space between the leaf sets.   It is a very hardy sedum.  You could plant it outside if you have the space.  Just break off a 3" pieces and insert the broken end into the ground.  It will root very fast.  I have found that it is somewhat sensitive to too much winter rain.  Looking a little rough by the time summer arrives, but it can always be cut back.  It fills in quite nicely.

The picture is an Angelina in my yard.  It has lost some leaves for winter.  The piece in the very back is shaded out by the rest.  It is etiolated like yours, just not as much.  The leaves have also started to bend backwards due the space between the leaf sets.  Not as bad as yours because it is outdoors.

[Sedum rupestre 'Angelina' at gardenia.net](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/sedum-rupestre-angelina)

[Heritage Perrenials Sedum 'Angelina'](http://www.perennials.com/plants/sedum-rupestre-angelina.html)

[image: Angelina etiolated]

Answer (score -1):

Fishhooks Senecio
Hanging succulents

Or

Senecio radicans
String of Bananas 
Although I cant find the exact cul
The clue is that it shares a pot with a succulent  :)

Watch online 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ROn26Kxa8aU&time_continue=26&feature=emb_title

https://www.joyusgarden.com/how-to-work-with-hanging-succulents/

[image]

Comment: Your plants have alternate leaves. The plant in question obviously has opposite leaves.   The plant in question is also in the Crassulaceae family.  Senecio is in Asteraceae family.    To be accurate neither is actually a Senecio at all, but of the genus Curio.